# Why my commandButton from JSF is not executing and returning an error ?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a form submited with ajax which normally must execute the removeArticle function. The problem is when I'm clicking the button, the function is never called and a beautiful error message is returned (displayed with alert) telling me : "serverError: class javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException CORBA OBJECT_NOT_EXIST 9998 Maybe; nested exception is: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1806 completed: Maybe". I'm using in another part a similar (almost) form for adding a cocktail. When I place my removeArticle calling into this other form it's executed ...

My code is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:component="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<ui:define name="title">Panier</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <c:if test="#{dataManagedBean.cartLength > 0}">
            <div id="cart-component">
                <h2>Panier</h2>
                <div class="well well-small">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <ui:repeat value = "#{dataManagedBean.cartContent}" var = "item" varStatus="status">
                            <h:form id="cocktail-panier">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="pull-left media-object span2">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <img src="resources/img/#{item.photoURIName}.#{item.photoURIExt}"
                                             alt="Photo du cocktail #{item.name}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="media-heading">
                                        #{item.name}
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="well well-small">
                                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                                            <ui:repeat value="#{dataManagedBean.getCocktailBeverages(dataManagedBean.getCocktailFull(item))}" var="bev" varStatus="status1">
                                                <component:ShowBeverageComponent item="#{bev}"/>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                            <div class = "span2 right">Quantité : #{dataManagedBean.getQuantityForCocktailInCart(item)}</div><br />
                                            <div class = "span2 right">Prix unitaire : #{item.price} €</div><br />
                                            <div class = "span2 right">Prix total : #{item.price * dataManagedBean.getQuantityForCocktailInCart(item)} €</div>
                                        </ul>                 
                                        <h:commandButton
                                            title=""
                                            value="Supprimer les articles "
                                            type="button"
                                            actionListener="#{dataManagedBean.removeArticle(item)}">
                                            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all" />
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                        <h:inputText id="qty"  maxlength="3" value="#{dataManagedBean.qty}" styleClass="input-mini" />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            </h:form>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    </c:if>
    <li class="thumbnail">
        <div class="totalPanier">
            <div class="total-cart"> Total:  #{dataManagedBean.getCartPrice()}€</div>
            <h:button class="totalPanier-button"
                      image="#{resource['img:btn_valider.png']}"
                      alt="valider" outcome="Form.xhtml" rendered="#{dataManagedBean.cartLength > 0}">
            </h:button>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the nested ui:repeat ! I replaced my 2 ui:repeat by 2 c:forEach and everything is working fine !

Answer (score 1):

HTML Elements IDs shouldn't have "-" like in your: `<h:form id="cocktail-panier">` AND `<div id="cart-component">`, this causes Problems in js. replace all these ids with underscore **cart_component**, or use Java Style like **cartComponent**

use commandButton like this:

```
<h:commandButton
                title=""
                value="Supprimer les articles "
                type="button">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all" listener="#{dataManagedBean.removeArticle(item)}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Ajax-Listener method like:

```
public final void removeArticle(final YourItemClass item){
```

you use jstl components. JSTL will run on build time, and if your Bean is requestScoped, then the render / action of commandbutton will not fire.

change your bean (if not) to ViewScope or SessionScope, and use rendered instead of `<c:if...`

somthing like:

replace this `<c:if test="#{dataManagedBean.cartLength > 0}">`

width this:

```
<h:panelGroup display="block" rendered="#{dataManagedBean.cartLength > 0}">
.....
```

ADDITIONALY:
you use templates. your template should somthing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css"/>

    <title>${pageTitle}</title>
```

In your XHTML Page where you use this template, you don't need to declare XML or HTML docType, and use your template directly:

```
<ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml"
....
```

Use `<h:head>` in your template instead of the `<head>`, else JSF will not include the jsf.js  in the document